# error: expected unqualified-id

Tags: c++

So, i have searched around for answers, and multiple people have got the same error response but i cannot see how their errors could fix my code.

I started trying out c++ yesterday, but i am experienced with mostly Python but also C#

I am making a simple contact book, just for learning.
I am not done with the class or any other implementation, just need this fixed first.

the exact error is

```
kontaktbok.cpp:9: error: expected unqualified-id before 'public'
```

And the code is here

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

bool running = true;

public class Contact
{
    private:
        string firstname   = "";
        string lastname    = "";
        string phonenumber = "";

    public:
        Contact()
        {
            this.firstname = "Alfred";
        }
};

int main()
{
        cout << "Welcome to the Contact book!" << endl <<
                "Made by X";
    while (running)
    {
        cout << "1. Add contact"    << endl
             << "2. List contacts"  << endl
             << "3. Quit"           << endl;
        cout << "Choice: ";
        string mystr;
        getline(cin, mystr);
        int choice;
        stringstream(mystr) >> choice;
        switch (choice)
        {
            case 1: cout << "asd";
            case 2: cout << "asd2";
            case 3: running = false;
            default : cout << "Invalid integer";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's both what i tagged it as and wrote in the description, sorry if i wasn't clear enough

Comment: No, you didn't fail to use the proper tags (as far as I can tell), I meant that `public class` resembles C# code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These changes will fix your issue, `public Class` is not valid C++, it should be just `class`:

```
class Contact
{
  private:
      string firstname ;
      string lastname  ;
      string phonenumber ;

  public:
    Contact()
    {
        this->firstname = "Alfred";
    }

  };
```

Also, you should be using `->` when dereferencing `this` it is a pointer not a plain `struct` or `class` in which using `.` would be valid. Also, member variables should be initialized in the constructor, if you want empty `string`s the default constructor constructs a [empty string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/).

Comment: `string firstname   = "";` in C++ in a class definition?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore meant to remove those, thanks

Comment: `string firstname   = "";` is valid C++11 (although it is unnecessary).

Comment: @juanchopanza Correct, I added a comment about default ctor

Answer (score 6):

`public class Contact` is not valid C++, use `class Contact` instead.